# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict': Python 3 Conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, networkx

I know that i am working with code from python 2 that no longer works in python 3. However, I am not sure how to adjust my code and I am currently unable to run python 2. Appreciate any insight.

I have already reviewed these existing threads, but I simply do not understand how to apply the learnings to my own use case:
[TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695479/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-dict-and-dict)

[TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464957/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-dict-and-dict)

**MY CODE**

```
nodes=random.randint(47,52)
p=random.uniform(0.05,0.08)
name="Erdos-Renyi random weighted graph"
G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(nodes,p)
maxw=random.randint(7,12)
weight=weight_attr(G,maxw)
w_edges=[(x,y,z) for (x,y),z in weight.items()]
G.add_weighted_edges_from(w_edges)
G=nx.Graph(G,name=name)
print ("Graph G is a %s with %i nodes, p=%.3f and %i edges\n" %(str(G),len(G.nodes()),p,len(G.edges())))

res = list(sorted(Counter(G.edges()), key=Counter(G.edges()).__getitem__, reverse=True))
for i in res:
    print ("Edge", i, "has weight", Counter(G.edges())[i]['weight'])
```

The code throws an error on this line:

```
res = list(sorted(Counter(G.edges()), key=Counter(G.edges()).__getitem__, reverse=True))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Maybe there's a different way?

Comment: For example, you're needlessly making (at least} three copies of the same Counter

Comment: @cricket_007 the first part of my code works fine - I am counting the nodes and edges of a weighted graph. The second part of the code is attempting to calculate the weight of each edge in my graph.

Comment: But why do you need a list when `G.edges()` probably already is one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know NetworkX, I'm not seeing the need to sort anything or make a list since you're just printing things

This should help you debug the code, at least and probably prints something similar in a different order

```
edge_counter = Counter(G.edges())

for k, v in edge_counter.items():
    print(f'edge {k} has value {v}')
```